# Partial View ignoring data set and not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am developing an application in ASP.NET MVC. I am working on a page that takes some user entered values and then gets a data set from them using a stored procedure. My preference is that the data is entered on the same page as it is displayed, so I am using AJAX and partial views to accomplish this. My code worked perfectly with a dummy set of simple data (simple string) but now that I am using a more advanced data set (Ienumerable) it no longer displays the partial view.

Here is part of my view (textboxes where data is entered are hidden for length purposes):

```
<!--SEARCH RESULTS PARTIAL FILLED BELOW-->
<div id="search-results">

</div>
<!---->


<script>
    function getSearchResults() {

        var SqlViewModel = {
           //assign textboxes to values to pass to controller (hidden)
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(SqlViewModel),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/Sql/Search/",
            success: function(result) {
                $('#search-results').html(result);
            }
        });        }


</script>
```

I grab the data from the textboxes, and then pass those values to my "Search" controller method using my ajax. (values are all passed correctly using SqlVieWModel)

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SqlViewModel sT)
    {
             //code for stored procedure

        var sql = //get stored procedure and parameters         

        SqlPartialViewModel obj = new SqlPartialViewModel();
        obj.SqlData = sql; //obj.SqlData is of type IEnumerable<Get_Result>

        return PartialView("_SearchResultsPartial", obj);
```

SqlPartialViewModel definition:

```
 public class SqlPartialViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Get_Result> SqlData { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I attempt to simply get this data to display in my partial view (_SearchResultssPartial.cshtml):

```
 @model SqlPartialViewModel

<table>
<tr>
   <th>//Display stuff</th>

</tr>
@foreach(var result in Model.SqlData)
{ 
<tr>
  <td>//Display stuff</td>
</tr>
}
```

Nothing displays, and I receive no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you Ajax call, you're expecting a `json` result from the server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(SqlViewModel),
        dataType: "json", <---- HERE
        contentType: "application/json", 
        url: "/Sql/Search/",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#search-results').html(result);
        }
});
```

But when you return a `PartialView` from an `ActionResult`, you're returning `html` type, not `json`type.

Just change the `dataType` to `"html"` or remove that line (so javascript will try to interpret by itself).